# Why Excel.Interop is returning a wrong HResult instead of FILE_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have been trying to load an excel file using the following code -

```
_workbook = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
               return _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If I provide a non-existent file name in the `fileName` parameter, it's throwing a generic COMException with the following error code - `0x800a03ec`

According to the Interop documentation, the .NET runtime should convert the HResult to a specific exception - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception?view=net-5.0

For this specific case, I was expecting to get a `FileNotFoundException` instead of the generic `COMException`. But since the HResult is not `FILE_NOT_FOUND`, its throwing the generic `COMException`. My question is why the interop is returning a wrong HResult? Is there anything wrong I have done here or its a bug in Excel.Interop?

Comment: It is not "wrong", error codes that start with 0x800a are used to shuttle an application-specific error back to your app.  Next four hex digits are that error code, so you'd google "excel error 1004" to find hits.  Yup, that happens a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the documentation does not state that. It says:

> The common language runtime transforms **well-known** HRESULTs to .NET Framework exceptions...

An arbitrary Excel HRESULT of 0x800a03ec is not "well-known", so .NET has no idea what to do with it, hence it remains a `COMException`.

Comment: I understand that! My question was why Excel.Interop is returning a wrong (to my perception) HResult? Am I doing something wrong here?